# Table filtering/searching with javascript/jquery based on tags

Tags: jquery, html, search, html-table

I have a table where each row includes a list of tags. I would like to be able to search for these tags and narrow the table down to only rows that contain that specific tag/s. So for example, if I type in my search box `2tag1 tagg` I would only get those two rows that contain these tags.

My table looks like this:

[image: The table]

My table HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tbl2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="span1">Merktu við spurningar</th>
                    <th class="span4"><strong>Spurning</strong></th>
                    <th class="span4"><strong>Vægi spurningar</strong></th>
                    <th class="span4">Tegund spurningar</th>
                    <th class="span2">Búin til</th>
                    <th class="span4">Tags</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbl2body">
                @for(question <- questions){
                    <tr id="row@question.spurningar_id">

                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="spurningar_id" id="@{question.spurningar_id}" onclick="enable(@question.spurningar_id)" value="@{question.spurningar_id}"></td>
                    <td>@{question.texti}</td>
                    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" size="6" name="vaegi" disabled="true" id="s@{question.spurningar_id}"></td>
                    <td><p>hehehe</p></td>
                    <td><strong>@{question.dagurbuidtil}</strong></td>
                    <td><ul id="tags"">
                        @for(tag <- question.tags){
                            <li class="well well-small">
                                @tag.leitarskilyrdi
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul></td>
                    </tr>}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have tried the following jquery, but this of course searches the whole row, not only the tags. If I select `#tags li` instead of `#tbl2body tr`, I am able to search the tags, but the rows do not dissapear.

How can I solve this problem?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li strong').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find('em').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#search').on("input", function(e) {
        var words = $(this).val().toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g);
        if (!words) {
            $('#tbl2body tr').show();
        } else {
            $('#tbl2body tr').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var show = words.some(function(word) {
                    return ~text.indexOf(word);
                });
                $(this).toggle(show);
            });
        }
    });

}); // end document ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat ID in a page, so instead of `<ul id="tags">` use class instead   `<ul class="tags">`.

Now only search for text within the tags `ul`

```
$('#tbl2body tr').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).find('ul.tags').text().toLowerCase();
            var show = words.some(function(word) {
                return ~text.indexOf(word);
            });
            $(this).toggle(show);
        });
```